# Dropbox Sync API not always updating

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using the Dropbox Sync API in a Android app to put Photo's on Dropbox.
The photos are stored in a DbxFile. Immediately after the creation of the files, I can re-open them without any problem, but once the files are uploaded, I can't open about half of the files on the mobile device. (On my PC, they are ok.) 
With the files that are no longer accessible, the Sync api seems to know there is a newer version, but for some reason they are not updated.

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromFile(String path) throws Exception {
    DbxFile dbxFile = dbxFileSystem.open(new DbxPath(path));

    DbxFileStatus newerStatus = dbxFile.getNewerStatus();

    if (newerStatus != null && newerStatus.isCached) {
    // this is +/- one-half of the time the case. Appears to be random?
        dbxFile.update(); //This is executed, but no update??
    }

    Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(dbxFile.getReadStream());
    dbxFile.close();
    return bitMap;
}
```

When I try to open a file that is no longer accessible, this line appears in LogCat:

```
libDropboxSync.so(open) file.cpp:329: opening at  (da618e76aab is latest)
```

By opening a file without problems, this line appears:

```
libDropboxSync.so(open) file.cpp:336: opening at da418e76aab (latest)
```

Why is the update not executed?
Any help is highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Sync API only starts to download new content for files when you open them. For the new version of the file to get downloaded, you need to open the file and hold it open (and register a listener so you know when the download has completed).

In your code, you're opening the file and then almost immediately closing it again. This means you will almost never get new versions of files and will just read the same cached version forever.

Except in very rare timing conditions, I would expect your condition `newerStatus.isCached` to never be true, since you just opened the file a line earlier. (Opening the file should give you the latest cached version, so there shouldn't be a newer version that's already cached... otherwise you would have gotten it already.)

Comment: There should not be a newer version. This happens at the moment that the file is uploaded. And even if there was a newer version, the original version should be able to load, and that's not the case. I have made a print-screen from the syncstatus and newerstatus. I hope this explains better the problem: ![print-screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2yc2ku69nsw20t5/Knipsel.PNG).
In case image is not loaded: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2yc2ku69nsw20t5/Knipsel.PNG

Comment: What do you mean by "the original version should be able to load, and that's not the case." You're having some sort of trouble reading the file? If so, what? (Is there an error?)

Comment: I get no bitmap. The BitmapFactory returns null. That means that the input stream cannot be used to decode a bitmap. Files that don't have a newerstatus can be processed, files with a newerstatus not.
in my view the problem is that the newerstatus is cashed, but the update will not be performed.

Comment: I'd say you should start debugging what's wrong with the file contents that makes it unparseable as a bitmap. It looks from your screenshot like it's a zero-byte file? Maybe you can figure out how that zero-byte file is getting written to Dropbox in the first place. What do you mean when you say "the update will not be performed?"

Comment: When I get the DbxFileInfo, the size is 0.
What happened:
- I save a picture to the DbxFileSystem with the function 'writeFromExistingFile'.

- I want to check the picture and load it back with the code in the question above. This is working.

- This keep working, but after a while, with some files, suddenly the size is 0, the sync status knows that there is a newer version (why?), the newer version is cached but not pushed to the file. This happens after the file is uploaded. On Dropbox, the pictures are ok. (This happens with some files, about half. With other files, there is no problem.)